# Cognos 11.2.2 - Nofification when a dataset is refreshed via a job

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

when I create a job and add a dataset refresh as a job step, I'd like to get a notification about a successful refresh. How could I do this please? The only idea that comes to mind so far - to create a dummy report and add it as the next job step, after the dataset (refresh). Then edit the delivery of this dummy report as Send report by email. And set the whole job as Run in sequence and disable Continuing on error.
This way, when I receive my dummy report in an email, I know my dataset has been refreshed.

Is there a better way to handle it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

How do you know if it is successful?  Because Cognos says it completed?  Because the schedule ran?

Your suggestion is a good one... mostly.

When you receive the report via email, that may not mean the dataset refreshed successfully.  So it shouldn't be a dummy report.  The report should use the dataset and send you some metrics that indicate that the dataset refreshed.

Here's the tricky bit.  If you put them both in the same job, are you sure the dataset refresh completes before the report runs?  Or could they just be started in that order, then the report runs before the dataset has completely refreshed?

A better solution may be to determine how long the dataset should take to refresh, then schedule the report to run at a time you are certain the dataset should be done refreshing, and notify you with relevant metrics from the dataset.

Comment: Hello dougp, thank you for your response.
How would I know the refresh is successful? When I receive the report, since the job is set not to continue on error. If it continues/finished, with the dummy report as the last step, I know the dataset refresh must have been successful.

The idea with checking the metrics is probably the safest, although it would require the person to know what exact metrics to expect. What if I need someone else to be notified about the dataset refresh? Everyone would need to know what metrics to expect.